# .NET MAUI, how to load the crash report to Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui

I'm working on a .NET MAUI application. The project is ready and it works fine on Android. It even works fine on my iPhone - both the Debug and Release version. However when I publish the application to App Store, it is rejected because it is crashing. I received several crashlog-9850E490-EC2E-4278-A4EE-8EB08D14C815.txt like files. I'm not sure how to *decode* them so I can see the call-stack where the crash happens.

For Windows project I always have a *.dmp file what I can open using Visual Studio and see the call-stack. However I'm not sure how to open such iOS crash report using Visual Studio for Mac.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was with Profile certificate. Not sure if the certificate became invalid because of *new Apple program license agreement* or due to deep-link support I added to my application.

Anyway this was pretty frustrating. The problem I see here that the compiler and the publish process did not warn about the certificate issue and I just can guess what could be the problem and do trial-error approach to solve the issue...

In this case it took 2 weeks until I find that this is the problem :-(